openapi-generator typescript-angular decorators not working in package
I'm generating an openapi spec using openapi-generator-cli (v2.13.4) with the following openapitools.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "7.4.0",
    "generators": {
      "ng": {
        "inputSpec": "./build/tsoa/swagger.json",
        "generatorName": "typescript-angular",
        "output": "./build/openapi",
        "skipValidateSpec": true,
        "additionalProperties": {
          "basePath": "https://us-central1-contecst.cloudfunctions.net/api"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

From this I'm publishing my own npm package, by including only the generated openapi spec folder.
But when I'm importing this package in my Angular client app with
{
  "dependencies": {
    "contecst": "^1.0.6",
    ...
  }
}

and importing DefaultService with
import { DefaultService } from 'contecst/build/openapi';

on ng serve I'm getting the error
X [ERROR] Transforming JavaScript decorators to the configured target environment ("chrome122.0", "edge122.0", "firefox115.0", "ios16.0", "safari16.0" + 7 overrides) is not supported yet

    node_modules/contecst/build/openapi/api.module.ts:6:0:
      6 │ @NgModule({
        ╵ ^

X [ERROR] Parameter decorators only work when experimental decorators are enabled

    node_modules/contecst/build/openapi/api.module.ts:20:17:
      20 │     constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: ApiModule,
         ╵                  ^

  You can enable experimental decorators by adding "experimentalDecorators": true to your
  "tsconfig.json" file.

although experimentalDecorators are enabled:
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    
  }
}

This is my angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "tecstures": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "tecstures:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "tecstures:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "tecstures:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

I'm using Angular 17.

Interestingly: If I generate the same openapi spec manually in my Anuglar client, to a folder src/openapi and import DefaultService from there, I'm not getting any errors.

Here is my tsconfig.app.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}


can you also provide tsconfig.app.json?
